# Can I control the pack() of a label in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this Label and would like to pack it in the GUI only when it is not empty; because, when I pack it without conditions, I get an empty line when it does not have the information I need. With the conditions I wrote it deletes the Label in all cases. Is there any solution for it?

I have `out_result = StringVar(value="")`

```
root = Tk() 
out_result = StringVar(value="")
scalOut=LabelFrame(root,text='Output visualization')
x=Label(scalOut,textvariable=out_result,font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight', 12), wraplength=450)
if out_result.get()=="":
     x.pack_forget()
if out_result.get()!="":
     x.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could you provide a [mre], because first of using grid in this case would seem better because it would be easier to put the label in the specific place after it is removed from there, second, it will change the rest of the layout when removed or added

Comment: Since you are using a *textvariable* you could add a trace to it and `pack` or `pack_forget` it each time it will be overwritten.

Comment: You are getting the valuie of `out_result` about a millisecond after you create it. The value won't have changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Label` to be placed only when the associated `StringVar` has any value, you can add a trace which will track the value of the variable and if there is some then place the `Label` else forget it:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, StringVar


def text():
    var.set(value='' if var.get() else 'some text')


def change_label(*args):
    if var.get():
        label.grid(column=0, row=1)
    else:
        label.grid_forget()


root = Tk()

Button(root, text='Add/remove text', comman=text).grid(column=0, row=0)

var = StringVar()
var.trace_add('write', change_label)
label = Label(root, textvariable=var)

Label(root, text='Some other label').grid(column=0, row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to get the `StringVar` by using its name but if you need to pass the `StringVar` instance to validation callback (here: `change_label`), you can use `lambda`: `var.trace_add('write', lambda *_, variable=var: change_label(variable))` then access the variable in the function by `args[0]`